# Extract all text with string positions from a PDF

Tags: java, pdfbox, pdf-parsing

This may seem an old question, but I didn't find an exhaustive answer after spending half an hour searching all over SO.

I am using PDFBox and I would like to extract all of the text from a PDF file along with the coordinates of each string. I am using their `PrintTextLocations` example (http://pdfbox.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/util/PrintTextLocations.html) but with the kind of pdf I am using (E-Tickets) the program fails to recognize strings, printing each character separately. The output is a list of strings (each representing a `TextPosition` object) like this:

```
String[414.93896,637.2442 fs=1.0 xscale=8.0 height=4.94 space=2.2240002 width=4.0] s
String[418.93896,637.2442 fs=1.0 xscale=8.0 height=4.94 space=2.2240002 width=4.447998] a
String[423.38696,637.2442 fs=1.0 xscale=8.0 height=4.94 space=2.2240002 width=1.776001] l
String[425.16296,637.2442 fs=1.0 xscale=8.0 height=4.94 space=2.2240002 width=4.447998] e
```

While I would like the program to recognize the string "sale" as an unique `TextPosition` and give me its position.
I also tried to play with the `setSpacingTolerance()` and `setAverageCharacterTolerance()` `PDFTextStripper` methods, setting different values above and under the standard values (which FYI are 0.5 and 0.3 respectively), but the output didn't change at all. Where am I going wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ah, the joys of PDF. Depending on what created it it could well be that »text« is just a collection of glyphs at certain positions so you'd have to do guesswork based on the positions to figure out where words and spaces are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Joey mentioned, PDF is just a collection of instructions telling you where a certain character should be printed.

In order to extract words or lines, you will have to perform some data segmentation: studying the bounding boxes of the characters should let you recognize those that are on a same line and then which one form words.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This is what I ended up doing: creating a set of rectangles for each PDF "template" and apply that to extract portions of text based on the position. This will require a lot of manual work to be maintained, but it seems the only reliable approach.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your Solution:
1. Reading File
2. Fetching Each Page to Text by using PDFParserTextStripper 
3. Each Position of the text will be printed by char.

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper;
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.TextPosition;
class PDFParserTextStripper extends PDFTextStripper {
    public PDFParserTextStripper(PDDocument pdd) throws IOException {
        super();
        document = pdd;
    }
    public void stripPage(int pageNr) throws IOException {
        this.setStartPage(pageNr + 1);
        this.setEndPage(pageNr + 1);
        Writer dummy = new OutputStreamWriter(new ByteArrayOutputStream());
        writeText(document, dummy); // This call starts the parsing process and calls writeString repeatedly.
    }
    @Override
    protected void writeString(String string, List<TextPosition> textPositions) throws IOException {
        for (TextPosition text : textPositions) {
            System.out.println("String[" + text.getXDirAdj() + "," + text.getYDirAdj() + " fs=" + text.getFontSizeInPt()
                    + " xscale=" + text.getXScale() + " height=" + text.getHeightDir() + " space="
                    + text.getWidthOfSpace() + " width=" + text.getWidthDirAdj() + " ] " + text.getUnicode());
        }
    }
    public static void extractText(InputStream inputStream) {
        PDDocument pdd = null;
        try {
            pdd = PDDocument.load(inputStream);
            PDFParserTextStripper stripper = new PDFParserTextStripper(pdd);
            stripper.setSortByPosition(true);
            for (int i = 0; i < pdd.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
                stripper.stripPage(i);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // throw error
        } finally {
            if (pdd != null) {
                try {
                    pdd.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File f = new File("C://PDFLOCATION//target.pdf");
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(f);
            extractText(fis);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (fis != null)
                    fis.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add a explanation, how you came to this result.

Comment: That code looks similar to the PrintTextLocations example.

Comment: Exactly the same concept.